# How to Use MySQL database in ionic framework

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework

I am developing an application in ionic framework. I want to use MySQL database in ionic framework, how can use MySQL in ionic?

Regards
kamran siddiqui

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to choose a backend framework in your preferred language. In an example [Asp.NET MVC Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for C#. Then you can run your queries in the backend and expose them via [REST service](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069) to your Ionic application.

Your ionic application can make http requests with Angular's [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service. Directly using a database from Ionic is not possible.